# Chrome Extension - onMessage in popup not receiving message from injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to Chrome extension development, and I want to do something super simple but I'm not sure why it's not working.
In essence, I want to:

- Run a popup.js script which programmatically injects a script
- Have the injected script get some data from the active tab
- use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send the data back to popup.js
- Do something when the data is received in popup.js (for example, displaying the active tab's URL in the extension popup)

The permissions in my manifest are "activeTab", "storage", "tabs".

Here is the code I'm trying to use for testing purposes

#### popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "injected.js"});                          

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(                                            
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){                                  
            console.log("message received!");                                
});
```

#### injected.js

```
var url = "";                                                                    

// get the url of the current tab                                                
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},                           
        function(tabs) {                                                         
                url = tabs[0].url;                                               
                console.log("running");                                          
});                                                                              

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"url": url});
```

The problem is that "message received!" never prints to the console when I use the debugger, however "running" will print just fine. I have looked at questions that seem to have a similar problem:

- [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Chrome extension : error when sending message back from injected script to background script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191477/chrome-extension-error-when-sending-message-back-from-injected-script-to-backg)
- [Message Passing Example From Chrome Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766990/message-passing-example-from-chrome-extensions)

None of the accepted answers seem to work for me. I've tried adding `return true;` to the onMessage event listener and it didn't seem to work. I'm also not getting any errors on the console in the debugger (from clicking "Inspect Popup"). I feel like I'm missing something trivial, but I don't know enough to make a guess at what it is. Is there a reason why onMessage isn't receiving anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) lists several chrome API allowed in a content script, not `chrome.tabs`.

> Solution: use `chrome.tabs` in a privileged page like the popup.

Like all Chrome API with a callback function `chrome.tabs.query` is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and invokes the callback after current function/context has been executed. So the next statement will only see the old `url` (empty string).

> Solution: process the received data right in the callback.

So in your scenario there's no need for a content script at all, along with `"tabs"` permission as you can see in ["activeTab" documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab): it automatically sets temporary permission after a user gesture such as clicking an extension toolbar popup.

Comment: Thank you! After deleting that it seems to work now :) I wish it had given an error of some kind. To clarify for the second solution, any asynchronous functions should process data in their callback to ensure that data isn't empty/undefined?

Comment: Yes, you can (and actually should) read about it in more detail, for example the answer I've linked or any other (better) tutorial/explanation. This is one of the most important basic things in JavaScript.